# Why electrons are relativistic in Graphene and non relativistic in vacuum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, graphene

If a free region in space has a potential difference of one volt, an electron in this region will acquire kinetic energy of 1 eV. Its speed will be much smaller than the speed of light hence it will be a non relativistic electron.

On the other hand conduction electrons in graphene are relativistic for the same potential difference.

Question is how come that when the electrons are in vacuum they are non relativistic, and when they are inside Graphene they are relativistic (for the same potential difference)?

Comment: I think you assume from the first sentence
$v\approx \sqrt{\frac{2 U_{eV}}{m_e}}<<c_0$ But your second sentence is a little bit misleading "conduction electrons in graphene are relativistic for the same potential difference". What do you mean? Electron mobility? Drift velocity? They are nonrelativistic. Or are you asking for the electron movement in a molecule? Well for Carbon the Schrödinger equation is a good approximation, you do not need the Dirac equation. You have to consider relativity for s electrons for heavy elements with high charge with e.g. ZORA - zeroth order relativistic approxi

Comment: Please do not answer questions if you are not familiar with the field. A quick google immediately brings up a wealth of information about the statement. In this case, there is no connection to the actual speed of light and the statement is a purely formal one regarding the equation of motion for quasiparticles.

Comment: @genneth You are right that this should not be an answer, but rather a comment on the given question to improve it. Pushed the wrong button :-(. But I am dissapointed too that a proper answer was not given by you, nor a reference. Hans de Vries finally clearified it, thnx.

Answer (score 8):

According to this article: http://physics.aps.org/articles/v5/24:

The statement that in graphene the "*conduction electrons are massless*" is because the energy levels (bands) are  **proportional** to their momenta.

So the $E = \sqrt{p^2+m^2}$ relation of a free electron becomes $E\propto p$ in graphene.

Massless particles travel all at the same speed because of the $E\propto p$ relation but this characteristic velocity in graphene is far below c though, only 0.3% of the speed of light.

The reason that the relation $E\propto p$ leads to a characteristic speed is due to the quantum mechanical wave character. $E$ is proportional to the phase changes in time, $p$ is proportional to the phase changes in space and therefor $p/E$ is proportional to the velocity. In the case that $E\propto p$ there is a characteristic velocity $v$ independent of the energy level.

> The most striking aspect of graphene is that its electronic energy
>   levels, or “bands,” produce conduction electrons whose energies are
>   directly proportional to their momentum. This is the energy-momentum
>   relationship exhibited by photons, which are massless particles of
>   light. Electrons and other particles of matter normally have energies
>   that depend on the square of their momentum.
>
> When the bands are plotted in three dimensions, the photonlike
>   energy-momentum relationship appears as an inverted cone, called a
>   Dirac cone. This unusual relationship causes conduction electrons to
>   behave as though they were massless, like photons, **so that all of them
>   travel at roughly the same speed (about 0.3 percent of the speed of
>   light)**. This uniformity leads to a conductivity greater than copper.

Hans

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand, electrons in graphene are not relativistic, although quasiparticles in graphene are indeed described by the massless Dirac equation. However, for graphene, the speed velocity in this equation is replaced by the Fermi velocity, which is much smaller.

Comment: If Dirac equation is used then they must be relativistic!

Comment: @Revo: In my book, a particle is relativistic if its velocity is comparable to the velocity of light. If you use a different definition, please give me a reference to a reliable source (if you just alluded in your comment  that the eigenvalues of velocity projections for a Dirac particle are always +-c due to Zitterbewegung, this does not seem to be relevant to your question). The velocity of the quasiparticles in graphene is always comparable to the "velocity of light" in the massless Dirac equation for graphene, but that "velocity of light" is not the genuine velocity of light.

Comment: Oh so let me make sure I get this correctly because it is new to me: so you are saying that the definition of relativistic means when the speed is comparable to the speed of light in the medium, right? I mean if the speed of light in a hypothetical medium is 1 cm/s say, then any particle with a speed close to 1 cm/s should be considered relativistic and it must be described by a relativistic equation, correct?

Comment: @Revo: No. I believe a particle is relativistic when its velocity is comparable to the velocity of light in vacuum. In most cases the velocity of speed in media is comparable to that in vacuum, so the clarification about vacuum is usually omitted. I agree that some exotic media may present exceptions. That does not mean that the particle that you describe must be described by a relativistic equation. It just so happens that quasiparticles in graphene can be described satisfactorily (to some extent) by an equation looking exactly like the massless Dirac equation with lesser "velocity of light"

Comment: As far as I know about Dirac equation it is the relativistic equation to correctly describes a relativistic spin half particle. If someone told me this particle or quasiparticle is correctly described by Dirac equation I would "naturally" think that this guy must be spin half and relativistic, relativistic means it moves with speed close to the speed of light. That is my understanding.

Comment: @Revo: I have two problems with your reasoning. While I agree that the standard Dirac equation is a relativistic equation and that it correctly describes a relativistic spin one half particle, that does not mean that if a particle is correctly described by the Dirac equation, it is necessarily relativistic, because the Dirac equation correctly describes slow particles as well. The above reasoning is correct, however, for the standard MASSLESS Dirac equation, as such an equation does not describe correctly slow particles. The other problem is described in another comment.

Comment: @Revo: The other problem is as follows. The massless Dirac equation used for quasiparticles in graphene is not the standard massless Dirac particles for the following reasons. While it looks exactly like the standard massless Dirac equation, the speed constant in this equation is much less than the velocity of speed in vacuum, so it only describes particles that are slow compared to the velocity of light in vacuum. Furthermore, the equation is not relativistic in the sense that it is not invariant under Lorentz transforms, it is only correct in the frame of reference of the graphene lattice.

Comment: @Revo: you are mistaken about the link between the Dirac equation and relativity. The Dirac equation correctly describes a single particle relativistically, but does not have to. One can use it to do other things. The statement "electrons in graphene are relativistic" is a purely formal statement about the lack of a rest mass for the quasiparticles.

Comment: @genneth Lack of rest mass means massless? massless fermions? If something is massless it must be travelling with speed of light.